# bootstrap 4 - javascript main file

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

**Bootstrap noob**
I downloaded a web template based on bootstrap 4, it had all the cool stuff that we used to make a website responsive.
The doubt what I have is why do we have to include javascript main file (main.js) in this code if we are not dealing with javascript. When I control clicked the file (ctrl+click) in VScode, it opened up and it had a long code starting out with a dollar ($) symbol which is I guess jquery (excuse me if I'm wrong).
Please help me out.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TheEvent - Bootstrap Event Template</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:300,400,500,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

 <footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-info">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="TheEvenet">
            <p>In alias aperiam. Placeat tempore facere. Officiis voluptate ipsam vel eveniet est dolor et totam porro. Perspiciatis ad omnis fugit molestiae recusandae possimus. Aut consectetur id quis. In inventore consequatur ad voluptate cupiditate debitis accusamus repellat cumque.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Terms of service</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Terms of service</a></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-contact">
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <p>
              A108 Adam Street <br>
              New York, NY 535022<br>
              United States <br>
              <strong>Phone:</strong> +1 5589 55488 55<br>
              <strong>Email:</strong> info@example.com<br>
            </p>

            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="copyright">
        &copy; Copyright <strong>TheEvent</strong>. All Rights Reserved
      </div>
      <div class="credits">
       
        
        Designed by <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>

 
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/superfish/hoverIntent.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/superfish/superfish.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

 
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>    /**the file I mentioned above **/

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.. Please try to post your question clearly. In it current form this is not  answerable. You have not posted the code where you are talking about `href` linking. Please refer [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question in SO.

Comment: yeah sorry, I get that. I'll post the entire code, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of Bootstrap components rely on a JavaScript file (written using jQuery) named `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`. This file is used to trigger animations and effects that make specific components (like the Carousel) work.

If you just want a responsive webpage that doesn't make use of these components, then you can just include the regular CSS file `bootstrap.min.css` or `bootstrap.css` and leverage the provided classes that make the layout work.

If you downloaded a web template from a third party, then it's likely that they created a single file `main.js` that includes some of Bootstrap JS code and perhaps some other customizations. That's why you see so many files being linked in `index.html`. The problem of downloading third party templates, is that most of the time you don't know what customizations or changes have taken place. As a result the project is difficult to follow and debug.

If you're a beginner, it's probably a good idea to start off using the official docs and then work you way from there.

[Read more about Bootstrap JS components here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Example minimal Bootstrap integration code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Minimal Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- more bootstrap structure goes here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example complete Bootstrap integration code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Complete Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- more bootstrap structure goes here -->
  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note: The examples assume the required files are downloaded locally into the corresponding `js` and `css` folders of your project. Also, `popper.js` is a necessary dependency to enable Tooltips.**